# Nuxt auth with laravel sanctum on Heroku

Tags: node.js, laravel, heroku, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to deploy a NuxtJS front with Laravel as API on Heroku.
Everything is working in local but when i'm login from the API on Heroku, the redirection after login doesn't work.
The Login request is working, i got the token as answer but the redirect doesn't work.
I notice that the CSRF Token cookie is `null` on Heroku.

There is my nuxt.config.js

```
      auth: {
    strategies: {
      laravelSanctum: {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: 'https://***-api.herokuapp.com',
        endpoints: {
          login: {url: '/api/login'},
          logout: {url: '/api/logout'},
          user: {url: '/api/me'}
        },
        token: {
          property: 'token',
        },
        tokenRequired: true,
        tokenType: 'Bearer'
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/login',
      home: '/'
    },
    localStorage: false
  },
```

On Laravel my `VerifyCsrfToken.php` is empty.

`sanctum.php` :

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),
```

`cors.php` :

```
    "Accept"=>"application/json",

    'paths' => ['api/*', '/user', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Comment: Did you looked up for some errors in your browser or Heroku's logs?

Comment: Also, when you're saying that it works locally: have you built the app and tried with `yarn start` or you tried only with `yarn dev`? Try to replicate the closest build to the one that will be on production. Also, check for env variables, it's a common thing people tend to forget.

Comment: @kissu i have been testing all of that, everything works in production mode even in local. I noticed using the Laravel API hosted on Heroku the setCookie methods returned by the csrf-cookie request doesn't set the cookie/the cookie is empty.